# Is there any open source project using graphviz c++ library?

Tags: graphviz

I have downloaded an open source project using graphviz c++ library, which visualizes and draws charts from or to dot files. But unfortunately, I deleted it from my computer. 
I really look forward to finding it because it is exactly what I need. I remember there are well-done encapsulated classes such as GVGraph, GVNode, GVEdge and so on. Can anyone tell me where it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can find it on the [resources page of graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/Resources.php).

Comment: Thanks! I found it, KGraphViewer.